# How to get an SSL certificate installed using Amazon Certificate Manager up on using CloudFront for a single EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

I’m using an Amazon EC2 instance to host my web application. The EC2 instance is in the APAC region. I wanted to use an SSL certificate from Amazon Certificate Manager.

For the above scenario, I have to go for either Elastic Load Balancing option or CloudFront.

Since my instance is in APAC region, I cannot go for Elastic Load Balancing, as load balancing is available only for instances in US East (N. Virginia) region.

The other option is to go for CloudFront. CloudFront option would have been easier if I was hosting my web application using Amazon S3 bucket. But I’m using an EC2 instance.

I requested and got an ACM certificate in the US East (N. Virginia) region.

I went ahead with CloudFront, and gave in my domain name (example.com) in the origin field, in the origin path; I gave the location of the application directory (/application), and filled in the http and https ports.

When the CloudFront distribution was deployed, I could only see the default self-signed certificate for the web application, and not the ACM certificate.

Your comments and suggestions are welcome to solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Why does CloudFront not work with EC2?

Comment: @tedder42 CloudFront does work with EC2, of course.  It works with any Internet-accessible web server, including [the one](https://cloudfront.sqlbot.net/) sitting under the end-table in my living room.  There are at least 3 different points of misconfiguration mentioned in the question, above.

Comment: An SSL *certificate.* Please.

Answer (score 2):

> I went ahead with CloudFront, and gave in my domain name (example.com) in the origin field,

This is incorrect.  The origin needs to be a hostname that CloudFront can use to contact the EC2 instance.  It can't be your domain name, because once you finish this setup, your domain name will point directly at CloudFront, so CloudFront can't use this to access the instance.

Here, use the public DNS hostname for your instance, which you'll find in the console.  It will look something lke ec2-x-x-x-x.aws-region.compute.amazonaws.com.

> in the origin path; I gave the location of the application directory (/application),

This, too, is incorrect.  The origin path should be left blank.  Origin path is string you want CloudFront to *prepend* to every request.  If you set this to `/foo` and the browser requests `/bar` then your web server will see the request as coming in for the page `/foo/bar`.  Probably not what you want.

> and filled in the http and https ports.

Here, you will need to set the origin protocol policy to HTTP Only.  CloudFront will not make a back-end connection to your server using HTTPS unless you have a certificate on the server that is valid and not self-signed.  The connection between the browser and CloudFront can still be HTTPS, but without a valid certificate on the instance, CloudFront will refuse to make an HTTPS connection on the back side.

Also, under the Cache Behaviors, you will need to configure CloudFront to either forward all request headers to the origin server (which also disables caching, so you may not want this) or you at least need to whitelist the `Host:` header so your origin server recognizes the request.  Add any other headers you need to see, such as `Referer`.

Enable query string forwarding if you need it.  Otherwise CloudFront will strip `?your=query&strings=off_the_requests` and your server will never see them.

If your site uses cookies, configure the cookies you need CloudFront to forward, or forward all cookies.

That should have your CloudFront distribution configured, but is not yet live on your site.

> When the CloudFront distribution was deployed,

This only means that CloudFront has deployed your settings to all of its edge locations around the world, and is *ready* for traffic, not that it is actually going to receive any.

> I could only see the default self-signed certificate for the web application, and not the ACM certificate.

Right, because you didn't actually change the DNS for "example.com" to point to CloudFront instead of to your web server.

Once the distribution is ready, you need to send traffic to it.  In Route 53, find the A record for your site, which will have the EC2 instance's IP address in the box, and the "Alias" radio button set to "No."  Change this to Yes, and then select the CloudFront distribution from the list of alias targets that appears.  Save the changes.

Now... after the old DNS entry's time to live (TTL) timer expires, close your browser (*all* browser windows), close your eyes, cross your fingers, open your eyes,  open your browser, and hit your site.

...which should be served via CloudFront, with the ACM certificate.

This probably sounds complicated, but should be something you can do in far less time that it took me to type this all out.

Comment: Hi Michael, My reply is in the answer. Please check. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Michael, now I'm getting a valid certificate when I login to my application. The home page however doesn't have that 'green icon', however it's not showing the self signed cert. The valid certificate green icon appears only when I login to the application.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Load Balancer is available in all the regions. The assumption that it is available only in US East is wrong. Check it out, maybe this alone solves your issue.

About SSL termination, you can enable the service on the ELB.

If in single node, you can SSL terminate on the web server itself, a cheaper solution.

Comment: If load balancing option is available for APAC region, it would solve my problem. But it's not. I have checked with AWS support, they also concurred with me, and advised me to proceed with cloudfront.

Comment: hello mate, when you refer to APAC, are you referring to the SEOUL region?

Comment: The issue is not whether ELB is available in the region.  Amazon Certificate Manager service is not integrated with ELB, yet, in any region except us-east-1.  To use a cert from ACM in any other region currently **requires** CloudFront.  In us-east-1, you can attach an ACM cert directly to an ELB.

Comment: Hi Maurizio, I'm in Singapore.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thank you so much for taking your time and helping me with the query. I proceeded with your suggestions.

'Also, under the Cache Behaviors, you will need to configure CloudFront to either forward all request headers to the origin server (which also disables caching, so you may not want this) or you at least need to whitelist the Host: header so your origin server recognizes the request. Add any other headers you need to see, such as Referer.'

I don't know what you mean by whitelisting the host. Under the whitelist box, what value do I have to give?

Since I wasn't sure about whitelisting the header, I proceeded with allow all header. And I forwarded all cookies.

In the origin settings, I don’t know what to give in the header name and header value. So, I gave the header name as ‘header1’, and value as my domain name ‘www(.)example(.)com’.

I have made the DNS change in Route 53 as you have suggested.

Now when I click www(.)example(.)com, I’m able to see https://www.example(.)com with a valid ACM certificate.

However, when I tried to access my application, https://www(.)example(.)com/application, the webpage is navigating to https://ec2-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/application/, and it’s showing the self-signed cert again.

I’m guessing there is some problem with DNS configuration in Amazon Route 53. Can you please tell me what changes do I have to do so that when I hit my application I can see a valid certificate?

Also, when I hit my application, my URL is changing to show ec2-x-x-x-x, instead of my domain name? Can you please tell me how to correct that?

Thank you so much.